# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class <unknown> while initializing progress bar

Tags: android, xml, progressdialog

This problem is not occurs every time its random.
and mostly getting on nexus 7.

I searched for it, but nothing helps me yet.
Please me out.

```
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187): Process: com.tmwtg, PID: 22187
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class <unknown>
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:477)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at com.tmwtg.common.CustomLoader.<init>(CustomLoader.java:18)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at com.tmwtg.profile.ProfilePage.onCreateView(ProfilePage.java:191)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    ... 26 more
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:282)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:937)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2092)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.widget.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.java:294)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.widget.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.java:246)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    at android.widget.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.java:242)
03-15 15:27:56.839: E/AndroidRuntime(22187):    ... 29 more
```

This is my CustomLoader class:

```
public class CustomLoader extends Dialog {

public CustomLoader(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public CustomLoader(Context context, int theme) {
    super(context, theme);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_progress_view);
}

public CustomLoader(Context context, boolean cancelable,
        OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
    super(context, cancelable, cancelListener);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

}

and i'm getting error on this line :

CustomLoader p;

```
p = new CustomLoader(getActivity(),
            android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
```

and this is my XML class :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/black_trans" >

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/anim_progress" />
```

i don't think its a memory problem, because when i add this.

```
@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "its a low memory sign.....",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

the toast is not displaying before crash.

Comment: seems like out of memory. Is it a very big image?

Comment: `anim_progress` seems to be taking up too much memory. Try using a downscaled image.

Comment: @ donfuxx yes its a camera image, about 2.5 MB, there is many more images.

Comment: @Raghav Sood r u suggesting to use low scale image in anim_progress ?? sorry didn't got u ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the problem, most of the guesses in comment were correct. it was a memory problem, actually, I create a new loader at initialization of each fragment, without finishing the last one, so its get crashed after swapping on 4-5 fragments. Now I'm initializing a static loader in my activity class and using the instance of that in fragments, Its solve my Problem. 
Thanks for comments.

Answer (score 0):

This error also pops up a lot when you try to use images in your app that are too big and cam cause memory issues so make sure the assets you are trying to use exist and that they aren't too big